# Angular regex for numbers gives true for only even length of numbers

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular9 and trying to check if the input is number or email or id number.
But while trying to check numbers it gives true for the odd length of numbers and false for even length of numbers.

Here is my code:

```
readonly patterns = {
    numbersOnly: /^[0-9]*$/gm,
    emailRegex: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/gm,
    numberRegex: /^\d+$/gm,
    idRegex: /^(\d{13}-\d{1,}100)?$/gm
  };

  patternOutput = {
    numbersOnly: false,
    emailRegex: false,
    numberRegex: false,
    idRegex: false
  };

  onInputChange(str: string) {
    console.log('=====',str,'=====');
    const numberOnlyRegex = this.patterns.numbersOnly;
    const emailRegex = this.patterns.emailRegex;
    const numberRegex = this.patterns.numberRegex;
    const idRegex = this.patterns.idRegex;


    this.patternOutput.numbersOnly=numberOnlyRegex.test(str);
    console.log('numbersOnly=>',this.patternOutput.numbersOnly);

    this.patternOutput.emailRegex=emailRegex.test(str);
    console.log('emailRegex=>',this.patternOutput.emailRegex);

    this.patternOutput.numberRegex=numberRegex.test(str);
    console.log('numberRegex=>',this.patternOutput.numberRegex);

    this.patternOutput.idRegex=idRegex.test(str);
    console.log('idRegex=>',this.patternOutput.idRegex);
  }
```

Here is the same running code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmhfvf

One thing I noticed when I checked the regex object formed is:
[image]
[image]

Here I can see there is a key named as `lastIndex` whose value in 1st object is 0 and 2nd object is 8

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `g` flag that way the regex doesn't try to match bast off of the last index it was on previously.

`g` lets it run multiple times through the same string finding all the matches. Hence why you are seeing it only match every other input.

```
  readonly patterns = {
    numbersOnly: /^[0-9]*$/m,
    emailRegex: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/m,
    numberRegex: /^\d+$/m,
    idRegex: /^(\d{13}-\d{1,}100)?$/m
  };
```

When it matches, it sets the last index to the end, but when it doesn't match, it resets the last index, so the next attempt works.